# How to set MainWindow title from core project in MVVMCross WPF Application

Tags: wpf, mvvmcross

I am developing a WPF app using MVVMCross. I started with the TipCalc Tutorial where we have the following MainWindow.xaml:

```
<views:MvxWindow  x:Class="UI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UI"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</views:MvxWindow>
```

My goal is to set the title from the core project. Therefore, I need a view model for the MainWindow. It seems, that this is implicitly defined in MVVMCross. Is there any chance to set the application title for a WPF application in MVVMCross via data binding?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add property Title on the current ViewModel then bind it later

```
Title="{Binding Title}"
```